# Modal class is passed as null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have found many questions related to my question but I am not able to resolve my issue that's why I am posting this question. I am using firebase as a real time database for the first time. With the below code I am trying to save the value to the firebase by clicking add button. But my application stops.Here is my logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.xyz.finance.MainActivity.addArtist(MainActivity.java:88)
        at com.example.xyz.finance.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:25)
        at com.example.xyz.finance.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

`Artist`modal class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Artist {
    private String artistId;
    private String artistName;
    private String artistGenre;

    public Artist(){
        //this constructor is required
    }

    public Artist(String artistId, String artistName, String artistGenre) {
        this.artistId = artistId;
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.artistGenre = artistGenre;
    }

    public String getArtistId() {
        return artistId;
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public String getArtistGenre() {
        return artistGenre;
    }
}
```

`Track` modal class

```
public class Track {
    private String id;
    private String trackName;
    private int rating;

    public Track() {

    }

    public Track(String id, String trackName, int rating) {
        this.trackName = trackName;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTrackName() {
        return trackName;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
}
```

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//we will use these constants later to pass the artist name and id to another activity
public static final String ARTIST_NAME = "com.example.xyz.finance.artistname";
public static final String ARTIST_ID = "com.example.xyz.finance.artistid";

        //view objects
        EditText editTextName;
        Spinner spinnerGenre;
        Button buttonAddArtist;
        ListView listViewArtists;

        //a list to store all the artist from firebase database
        List<Artist> artists;

        //our database reference object
        DatabaseReference databaseArtists;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getting the reference of artists node
        databaseArtists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("finance");



        //getting views
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        spinnerGenre = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenres);
        listViewArtists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewArtists);

        buttonAddArtist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddArtist);


        //list to store artists
        artists = new ArrayList<>();


        //adding an onclicklistener to button
        buttonAddArtist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        //calling the method addArtist()
        //the method is defined below
        //this method is actually performing the write operation

        addArtist();
        }
        });
        }

    /*
    * This method is saving a new artist to the
    * Firebase Realtime Database
    * */
private void addArtist() {
        //getting the values to save

        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String genre = spinnerGenre.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //checking if the value is provided

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) ) {

        //getting a unique id using push().getKey() method
        //it will create a unique id and we will use it as the Primary Key for our Artist

        String id = databaseArtists.push().getKey();

        //creating an Artist Object



        Artist artist = new Artist(id, name, genre);
        //Saving the Artist
        databaseArtists.child(id).setValue(artist);

        //setting edittext to blank again
        editTextName.setText("");

        //displaying a success toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Artist added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
        //if the value is not given displaying a toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Debug method `addArtist()` . Seems like `spinnerGenre.getSelectedItem()` returning `null`  . Or whatever on `MainActivity.java:88`.

Comment: You've got quite a lot of code there! Please consider creating a smaller, cleaner example of your issue to make it easier to understand and answer. Also, adding some examples of what you've already tried yourself to fix the issue would be very helpful. Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more tips.

Comment: On which line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: In addArtist()..I cant findout what is the error@ADM@Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please try code written between **"Edit Started"** and **"Edit Ended"**

```
private void addArtist() {
        //getting the values to save

        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String genre = spinnerGenre.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //checking if the value is provided

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) ) {

        //getting a unique id using push().getKey() method
        //it will create a unique id and we will use it as the Primary Key for our Artist

        String id = databaseArtists.push().getKey();

        //creating an Artist Object

//Edit Started
          Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
          params.put("id", id);
          params.put("name", name);
          params.put("genre",genre);

        //Saving the Artist
        databaseArtists.child(id).updateChildren(params)

// Edit Ended

        //setting edittext to blank again
        editTextName.setText("");

        //displaying a success toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Artist added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
        //if the value is not given displaying a toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mate! Happy Coding!